# **Take the damped nonlinear pendulum equation $ \ \ θ′′ + μθ′ + (g/L) \ sin θ = 0 \ $ for some μ > 0 (that is, there is some friction)

Tags: nonlinear-system

**Take the damped nonlinear pendulum equation  $ \ \ θ′′ + μθ′ + (g/L) \ sin θ = 0 \ $ for some μ > 0 (that is, there is some friction). a) Suppose  μ = 1 and $ \frac{g}{L}  = 1 $ for simplicity, find and classify the critical points. b) Do the same for any μ > 0 and any g and L, but such that the damping is small, in particular, $ μ^{2} < 4(\frac{g}{L}) $.** $$ $$ **(a)** If $ \mu=1 \ \ and \ \ \frac{g}{L}=1 $  , then the equation becomes $ \theta''+\theta'+\frac{g}{L} \sin \theta =0 $. Let $ w=\theta' $ , then the equation becomes a 2 dimensional system as follows  \begin{align}  w'=-w+\frac{g}{L}\sin \theta \\ \theta'=w \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \end{align}. Then the critical points are obtained from  \begin{align} w'=0 \ \ implies\  \ w-g/L \sin \theta=0 , \\ \theta'=0 \ \ implies \ \ w=0,   \end{align}. Hence the critical points are $ (0,0)  , (0 , \pi ) , ..... $ . **Am I right ? and what the part (b)  ?  please help me**

Comment: would you help me doing part (b) ?

Comment: But given $ \mu>0 $  , then $ \mu=\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}} $ . But again the same critical points are obtained . So basically what is the difference between the two cases ?

Comment: one thing , is not it  $ \mu= 2 \sqrt{\frac{g}{L}}$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57230/discussion-between-mabmath-and-moo).

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

To classify the equilibrium points evaluate the jacobian matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
g/L \cos(\theta)& -1
\end{pmatrix}.

at ech equilibirium point and look eigenvalues .